# How do I point out violations for BCNF?

Tags: database, schema, computer-science, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have a databases midterm this week and I am having trouble with identifying violations for BCNF. I know how to decompose relations and to find which is the key and which are the superkeys. I can also write out the FDs that are implied. I was watching the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTFyG5o8-EA.

To sum it up, the lady explaining starts to apply the BCNF algorithm to the following relation (she uses the student example but I've converted it into letters to simplify it):

R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H) with FDs: A -> BCG, G -> H, D -> EF.

I am aware that the key is AD because the closure of it is AD+ = ABCDEFGH.
She says that all the FDs presented are violations and begins applying the algorithm:

BCNF attempt #1:

R1 = D -> EF (D+ = DEF) *// no violation but why? Wasn't it just a violation?*

R2 = ABCDEFG - (DEF - D) = ABCDGH *// violation, also confused as to why? It contains both keys.*

---

BCNF attempt #2 on R2:

R3 = G -> H (G+ = GH) *// no violation because only two attributes GH, I believe*

R4 = ABCDG *// violation, but I don't know why.*

---

BCNF attempt #3 on R4:

R5 = A -> BCG *// no violation (?)*

R6 = AD *// no violation (?)*

**Final Relations:** R1, R2, R5, R6.

Answer (score 2):

The violations in `R` are partial and transitive functional dependencies. When these FDs are extracted as separate relations, they're no longer partial or transitive. This is the reason we normalize, so it should be no surprise that they stop being violations when isolated.

**R1/R2**: In `R`, `EF` depends on `D`, a subset of the candidate key `AD`, so it's a partial dependency. When extracted to `R1` which has only `D` as a candidate key, the dependency is no longer partial. The remainder of `R` becomes `R2` which still contains a partial FD (`A -> BCG`) and transitive FD (`A -> G -> H`).

**R3/R4**: In `R2`, `A -> G -> H` so `G -> H` is a transitive FD. When extracted to `R3`, it's no long transitive. The remainder of `R2` becomes `R4` but still contains a partial FD (`A -> BCG`).

**R5/R6**: In `R4`, `BCG` depends on `A` which is a subset of the candidate key `AD`. When extracted to `R5` which has only `A` as a candidate key, the dependency is no longer partial. The remainder of `R4` becomes `R6` which doesn't have any non-trivial FDs.

Your final answer should be R1, **R3**, R5 and R6.

PS. Note that not all BCNF violations can be categorized as partial or transitive functional dependencies.

Comment: @philipxy It's not difficult to show that partial and transitive FDs violate BCNF. My point wasn't to categorize BCNF violations, but to give a valid (and familiar) explanation of the violations in OP's problem, which just happen to be describable in those terms. For completeness, I added a PS.

Comment: @reaanb It's easy to show partial dependencies of non-prime attributes on CKs violate BCNF since they violate 2NF--but then, they are FDs not out of SKs. It is not easy to show exactly which partial, transitive and other dependencies violate BCNF without reference to FDs not out of SKs. And since the *latter* matter, why bother? Partial & transitive, familiar notions from 3NF, are not useful here--unless you use the definition that uses 3NF plus every element of the set difference between determined and determinant sets being a prime attribute--which, again, is not re partial or transitive.